# Isolate dependencies while building object relationships in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, oop, relationship

I'm practicing OOP for the first time by modeling my application domain (public high school) as objects, and I'm stuck on how to create relationships between the classes without introducing lots of external dependencies.

I have lots of relationships I want to construct, so in hopes of learning the general principle I'm giving two classes and sample objects here to illustrate the difficulty I'm having.

I have two classes `Grade`and `Transcript`. Every instance of `Transcript` has an instance variable `@mark`, which right now is a string. I collected all the instances of each class a `grades` hash and a `transcripts` hash.

**Question: How can I modify these classes so that `@mark` references the corresponding `Grade` instance?**

(or, is that the wrong approach entirely?)

`Grade` has an instance for every possible final grade students can receive

```
class Grade
  attr_accessor :mark, :alpha_equivalent, :numeric_range_low, :numeric_range_high, :numeric_qquivalent, :pass_fail_equivalent, :description

  def initialize(args)
    @mark = args["Mark"]
    @alpha_equivalent = args["AlphaEquivalent"]
    @numeric_range_low = args["NumericRangeLow"]
    @numeric_range_high = args["NumericRangeHigh"]
    @numeric_equivalent = args["NumericEquivalent"]
    @pass_fail_equivalent = args["PassFailEquivalent"]
    @description = args["Description"]
  end
end
```

Sample object from the grades hash:

```
grades["100"] =>
#<Grade:0x007f9fcb077d68
 @alpha_equivalent="100",
 @description="100 out of 100",
 @mark="100",
 @numeric_equivalent="100",
 @numeric_range_high="100",
 @numeric_range_low="100",
 @pass_fail_equivalent="P">
```

`Transcript` has instances for every final grade the student has ever received for all the courses they've studied

```
class Transcript
    attr_accessor :student_id, :last_name, :first_name, :grade, :official_class, :school, :year, :term, :course, :course_title, :mark, :pass_fail, :credits

    def initialize(args)
        @student_id = args["StudentID"]
        @last_name = args["LastName"]
        @first_name = args["FirstName"]
        @grade = args["Grade"]
        @official_class = args["OffClass"]
        @school = args["school"]
        @year = args["Year"]
        @term = args["Term"]
        @course = args["Course"]
        @course_title = args["Course Title"]
        @mark = args["Mark"]
        @credits = args["Credits"]
        @grade_entry_cohort = args["GEC"]
  end
end
```

Sample object from the transcripts hash:

```
transcripts["foobar-COURSE1-100"] =>
  #<Transcript:0x007f9fce8786b8
   @course="COURSE1",
   @course_title="Example Course",
   @credits="5",
   @first_name="FOO",
   @grade="100",
   @grade_entry_cohort="V",
   @last_name="BAR",
   @mark="100",
   @official_class="000",
   @school="1",
   @student_id="0123",
   @term="1",
   @year="2000">
```

I'm instantiating all the objects from CSV source files and then collecting them into a hash because I wanted to be able to address them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to want `Transcript#grade` to return a `Grade` instance. So let's make a method for that:

```
class Grade
  def self.all
    @all ||= {}
  end

  def self.find(mark)
    all[mark]
  end
end
```

Now, `Grade.all` needs to be populated. This could be achieved like this from your CSV:

```
grade_args = %w[alpha_equivalent description mark numeric_equivalent numeric_range_high numeric_range_low pass_fail_equivalent]
CSV.parse { |row| Grade.all.merge(csv['mark'] => Grade.new(row.slice(*grade_args)}
```

Now, we can modify `Transcript` like this:

```
class Transcript
  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

  def grade
    @grade ||= Grade.find(args['mark'])
  end

  private

  attr_reader :args
end
```

Comment: The `||=` operator you mentioned sounds really useful, thank you! I definitely would like to use the second approach of defining a method, but the challenge I'm facing is that the attributes about the grade are contained in the instance of the `Grade` class. When I feed `args` to transcript, the value for grade is a string.

What I need to do is figure out how to write a method which will use the string from args to lookup the correct instance in the grades hash, which has all the instances of grade.

Comment: Basically because there are two source files I'm feeding into my program, one has information about what all the grades mean, and the other lists what grade students recieved

Comment: Updated to address your question more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've created the `grades` hash earlier:

```
# read args from csv
# id built from first, last, course, and grade
transcripts[id] = Transcript.
  new(args.merge('Mark' => grades[args['Mark']])
```

It uses `Hash#merge` to extend `args` with an instance of `Grade` that was built earlier.

Comment: So from your description it sounds like this basically looks up the record matching id, and then does it sort of amend the existing instance by setting a new value for the `mark` instance variable? When I see the `Transcript.new` call it appears like it's building a new instance, but you mention that it's extending the instance found in `transcripts` hash?

Comment: @zqe this code would replace the `transcripts` building that you're already doing.